# How to add object value to style attributes in Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to add style width, height, and colour in input tag.

```html
<table>
 <td *ngFor="let y of x" >
      <input  type="{{y.cellNumber}}"  src="{{y.src}}"  value="{{y.name}}" height="{{y.height*2}}" width="{{y.width/2}}" style="height:{{y.height}}px;width:{{y.width}}px">    
 </td> 
</table>
```

But inside the style am unable to set object value. Is there any other way to set object value inside the style within input tag.

Comment: Check out ngStyle https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
<table>
 <td *ngFor="let y of x" >
      <input 
      type="{{y.cellNumber}}"  
      [src=]"y.src"   
      [value]="y.name" 
      [style.height.px]="y.height/2"  
      [style.width.px]="y.width/2" >    
 </td> 
</table>
```

Another approach would be to use `ngStyle`, like this:

```
<table>
 <td *ngFor="let y of x" >
      <input 
      type="{{y.cellNumber}}"  
      [src=]"y.src"   
      [value]="y.name" 
      [ngStyle]="getStyle(y)">    
 </td> 
</table>    


getSyle({ width, height }) {
  return {
    width: `${width/2}px`,
    height: `${height/2}px`,
  };
}
```

Comment: Please upvote the answers that help you. Also consider accepting this as a solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NgStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle):

```
<table>
 <td *ngFor="let y of x" >
      <input [type]="y.cellNumber" [src]="y.src" 
             [value]="y.name" [height]="y.height*2" [width]="y.width/2" 
             [ngStyle]="{ 'height.px':y.height, 'width.px': y.width}">    
 </td> 
</table>
```